# Sort an array of numbers into two arrays of equal length in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have an array of 20 different numbers which contains ranking of students.

I want to split this array into two sub arrays of equal length i.e 10
I also want the sum of all numbers within each array to be close.

For example, in sub-array A there could be a total sum of 56 and in sub-array B there could be a total sum of 57.

I am using PHP.

I sort the main array here and would like to assign index[0] to sub-array A and index[1] to sub-array B, and keep repeating this until both arrays are filled.

My approach works but i think its not great and not dynamic.
I interate through the main original array for [i] and then add that to the first sub-array, then I set i = i+2 so that I get every second value and store them in the first array.
I then remove the value at index[i] from the main array.
What is left over is now sub-array B.

```
$kids = array (8,5,6,9,3,8,2,4,6,10,8,5,6,1,7,10,5,3,7,6);
sort($kids);

$arrlength = count($kids);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
 echo $kids[$x];
 echo "<br>";
}


 $teamA = array();
 $teamB = array();


 $i = 0;

    while ($i < $arrlength)
    {
        #echo $kids[$i] ."<br />";
        array_push($teamA, $kids[$i]);
        unset($kids[$i]);  
    
        $i += 2;
    }
    $teamB = $kids;
    
   
    
  print_r($teamA);
  print_r($teamB);
```

My Output is :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 6 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 
8 [8] => 8 [9] => 10 ) 
The sum here of all values is = 58



Array ( [1] => 2 [3] => 3 [5] => 5 [7] => 5 [9] => 6 
[11] => 6 [13] => 7 [15] => 8 [17] => 9 [19] => 10 )
The sum here of all values is = 61
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have no real experience with PHP or its built in functions so sorry if this is a basic question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in helper function of php, [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). You can read about it in the link I provided.

Here's how you can use in to achieve what you want:

```
$kids = array (5,7,6,8,3,8,2,4,6,10,8,5,6,10,7,6,5,3,7,6);
sort($kids);

$arrlength = count($kids);

$arrayA= array_slice($kids, 0, $arrlength / 2);
$arrayB= array_slice($kids, $arrlength / 2);
```

**Output**

```
// $arrayA
array:10 [▼
0 => 2
  1 => 3
  2 => 3
  3 => 4
  4 => 5
  5 => 5
  6 => 5
  7 => 6
  8 => 6
  9 => 6
]

// $arrayB
array:10 [▼
0 => 6
  1 => 6
  2 => 7
  3 => 7
  4 => 7
  5 => 8
  6 => 8
  7 => 8
  8 => 10
  9 => 10
]
```

**Another approach for achieving what you asked**

```
$kids = array(8,5,6,9,3,8,2,4,6,10,8,5,6,1,7,10,5,3,7,6);
sort($kids);

$teamA = array();
$teamB = array();

foreach($kids as $i => $kid){
    if($i % 2){
        array_push($teamA, $kid);
    } else{
        array_push($teamB, $kid);
    }
}
```

It will generate the same output and sum as you want.

Comment: I like that approach, however when you add the values up in each new array, their totals are not close. I have updated my question, maybe it can provide more information.

Comment: @EamonMac Ok, I'm a little confused here by your provided output. By what logic you sorted your arrays? They are not even or odd, and they are also not unique. Can you explain how did you sorted your array?

Comment: i want to sort my array into 2 new arrays. Each array has to contain 10 numbers from the main array of 20 numbers. The sum of these 10 numbers in each array has to be close. Each array represents test student rankings so i want the total ranking (i.e the sum) of each array to be similar. For example, add everything in array A up and it = 45 or so. Do the same for array B and it is = to 46.

Comment: @EamonMac Got it. If you have a static array then your theory of same (or near to same) is okay. If you have a dynamic array, then your sum can get from 0 to +4 (or maybe more). Means sum of array `$teamA` could be **59** and sum of `$teamB` could be **63**. which is +4 in difference.

Comment: And if you're okay with it then your approach is fine. Since your requirement is so unique or custom there is no in-built helper function that I'm aware of for that to achieve. However there are many other approaches and ways to achieve your goal. I'm updating my answer for another way to achieve your goal.